# Научиться - какой способ образования: приставочный или суффиксальный?

Tags: словобразование

Поясните, пожалуйста, свой ответ.

Comment: Предложите свой вариант, а мы скажем: правильно или нет. За Вас делать домашние задания тут никто не будет.

Comment: Иногда в домашних заданиях бывают сложности, это такой случай, мы можем подсказать, как избежать ошибки. Она и так дала свой вариант: приставочный или суффиксальный.Просит разрешить сомнение

Comment: Я уже давно не ученица.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лорана, нужно составить цепочку, чтобы не ошибиться: учить-учиться-научиться. Получается приставочный. В глаголах несов. вид первичен по отношению к совершенному.

Comment: А почему не учить - научить - научиться?

Comment: Составьте видовые пары: учить-научить; учиться-научиться.Что такое научиться?-это завершённое действие глагола учиться. Если бы суффиксальный, мы бы сказали: что такое научиться? -это научить себя. Но ведь это не то значение, научиться можно и у другого. А вообще не надо мудрствовать. Если при отсечении приставки остаётся слово с этим же значением, значит, приставочный.Учиться-научиться -всё в порядке, видовая пара.

Comment: А слово   смеяться как образовано?

Comment: Слово "смеяться" является непроизводным - общеславянское, имеющее соответствия в индоевропейском языке. Современная форма возникла на основе древнерусского "смѢятися". Производным является слово "смех".

Answer (score 2):

В качестве дополнения к ответу:

Мы имеем следующую словообразовательную цепочку: учить - учиться - научиться, умыть - умыться - умываться. В этих случаях образование слова с новым значением с помощью частицы СЯ является первичным (приоритетным)  по отношению к образованию видовой пары с помощью приставки или суффикса.

В словаре Ефремовой указывается. что частица СЯ является самостоятельным словообразовательным элементом с общим значением устранения переходности, при этом указывается большое количество частных значений частицы СЯ,например:собственно возвратное (беречься), взаимообратное  (обниматься), способность к действию (кусаться), действие внутри субъекта (радоваться. пениться)и др.

Comment: Скажите, а тогда "учиться" какое? если я правильно поняла, то оно и возвратное, и взаимообратное?  (и способность к действию :) )

Comment: Классификация значений частицы СЯ может не совпадать в разных источниках, в том числе в терминах. У Ефремовой  собственно-возвратное действие имеет объектом ФИЗИЧЕСКОЕ тело самого субъекта действия (завиваться, закутаться). Общевозвратным она называет действие,которое замыкается в сфере действия субъекта и вызывает изменение его ВНУТРЕННЕГО состояния.Скорее всего, слово "учиться" подходит под это определение.

Answer (score 0):

учиться- научиться. Не вижу в данном случае словообразовательных морфем. Приставка -на- является формообразующей, поскольку с её помощью образуется совершенный вид уже имеющегося глагола.
спасибо за информацию. Но, даже после ваших пояснений, я не вижу в данных глаголах слов, отличающихся по своему лексическому значению, т.е. разных, новых слов. Да, есть такие глаголы, как бросать - бросить. Но ведь они отличаются не только по своему  морфемному составу (суффикс основы), но и тем, что приобретают новое  лексическое  значение с присоединением приставок. бросить мяч- забросать "мячами" и т.п.
 Делать - сделать, писать- написать - все эти глаголы, сохраняя первоначальное  лексического значение, отличаются только видом, который меняется с присоединением приставок  "с" или  " на" , рассматриваемых  в подобных случаях как формообразующий элемент: нет нового лексического значения. Но слово "переделать" - новое лексическое значение, значит, приставка "пере" - словообразующая. Естественно, что при определении глагольных форм, заданий типа: назвать формы одного и того же слова, следует учитывать вид. Между прочим, такой подход, который я нахожу вполне обоснованным, уже прослеживается в заданиях по централизованному тестированию. С другой стороны, я понимаю и ваш подход, который ещё совсем недавно был и "моим", но изменился в связи с новой тенденцией рассмотрения подобных случаев. С уважением  tamy
  "Выполняя словообразовательный анализ, следует помнить, что формообразовательные суффиксы и приставки в этом процессе никакого участия не принимают. Следовательно, называть формообразующий суффикс, той морфемой, с помощью которой образуется новое слово,ошибочно."  К формообразующим суффиксам относятся следующие: 1) -ть,-ти, чь - суффиксы, с помощью которых образуется инфинитив   2) суффикс -л- образующий форму прошедшего времени 3) суффиксы -вш-, -ш-, -нн-, -енн-, -т., -ущ-, -ющ-, ...- - ом-, - ем-, -им-, 4) суффиксы деепричастий:  - а-, -я-, - вши-, -в, и все другие суффиксы, образующие новые формы, но не участвующие в образовании новых слов: суффиксы степеней сравнения прилагательных, наречий + суффиксы множественного числа некоторых существительных:- ер- дочь - дочери; -ен- имя - имена и т. п.   Успехов
"Хороший" вопрос  насчет основы. надо подумать. как на него ответить. Утро вечера мудренее. спокойной ночи, Людмила Уже нашла ответ для себя по поводу основы. Ввиду того что основа- это "часть слова, выражающая его лексическое значение", не включающая формообразовательные суффиксы, не меняющие этого значения, значит, и формообразующие приставки, на существование которых обратили внимание лишь в последнее время,не войдут в основу: их отсутствие также не меняет лексического значения слова. Всего хорошего. 
Думаю, София, вы просто сделали описку, указав, что все глагольные формы образуются от двух основ.  В действительности они образуются от трех основ. Все формы настоящего времени - от основы настоящего времени: строить-стро-им -стро-им-ый, стро-ят-стро-ящ-ий; писать - пишут- пишущий; все формы прошедшего времени - от основы инфинитива, реже- от основы будущего времени: пройти - пройдут - пройденный - пройдя. Правда то, что эти основы у некоторых глаголов иногда совпадают. Думаю, что стоит прекратить дискуссию на эту тему. Всего хорошего.

Comment: Любой глагол имеет категорию вида, то есть является глаголом совершенного или несовершенного вида (бывают также двувидовые глаголы). Многие глаголы образуют видовые пары. Видовая пара - это  противопоставление ДВУХ глаголов, тождественных  по лексическому значению и различающихся грамматическим значением вида. Это два РАЗНЫХ глагола, каждый из них имеет свою начальную форму - инфинитив.

Comment: Форма слова - это основа + окончание (изменяемая часть слова). Глаголы изменяются по лицам и числам или по числам и родам. Они не могут изменяться по "виду", который будет выражать, к примеру, приставка. Даже суффикс прошедшего времени Л не образует форму, а  входит в основу глагола, и для образования формы  прошедшего времени  используются окончания.

Comment: Tamy,а если Вы будете разбирать НАУЧИТЬСЯ по составу, Вы приставку НА- будете включать в основу? Если она формообразующая, значит, нет? Дело в том,что сейчас подход такой:"Говоря о приставках, можно признать, что  в глаголе приставка выполняет не только словообразовательные функции, но может быть осложнена формообразовательными функциями, участвуя в видообразовании".А вообще-то это словообразовательный аффикс, за исключением НАИ-(образует форму превосходной степени-наилегчайший)

Comment: А в каких заданиях тестирования прослеживается такой подход? Я как-то не видела.

Comment: У глагола есть 4 формы (личная и три неличные (инфинитив, причастие, деепричастие). Общими для всех четырех форм являются категории вида, залога и переходности/непереходности. Все формы глагола образуются от двух основ: основы инфинитива и основы прошедшего времени. Эти основы могут совпадать, а могут отличаться на глагольный суффикс. Форма прошедшего времени образуется присоединением суффикса Л к основе инфинитива. Получается, что форму глагола образуют формообразующий суффикс и изменяемое окончание.